# Input/Radio Bottom Resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to keep the size of the questions as it is, and make the input/radio button size smaller.  I tried several ways, even methods from this website https://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/radio-button/.  Nothing seems to be working......

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="questions">
                What is the name of Black Panther's home?
                </br>
                <input id="choice" type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="false">K'un Lun</input>
                <input id="choice" type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="true">Wakanda</input>
                <input id="choice" type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="false">Kamar Taj</input>
                <br>
                How did Dr Strange defeat Dormammu?</br>
                <input id="choice" type="radio" name="secondQuestion" value="false">Built An Energy Prison</input>
                <input id="choice" type="radio" name="secondQuestion" value="true">Create a Time Loop</input>
                <input id="choice" type="radio" name="secondQuestion" value="false">Froze Time</input>
                <br>
                Which hero secretly has a family?</br>
                <input id="choice" type="radio" name="thirdQuestion" value="true">Hawkeye</input>
                <input id="choice" type="radio" name="thirdQuestion" value="false">Wakanda</input>
                <input id="choice" type="radio" name="thirdQuestion" value="false">Kamar Taj</input>
                </div>
                <div>
                <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitted()"/>
                </div>
                <p id="firstPara"></p>
                <p id="secondPara"></p>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. There is no closing `</br>` or `</input>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to apply styles directly to the radio buttons as such:

```
#choice {
  width: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/ftbaw0ps/1/

Please use correct HTML syntax, like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="questions">
    <div>
      <p>What is the name of Black Panther's home?</p>
      <input id="choice" type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="false">K'un Lun
      <input id="choice" type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="true">Wakanda
      <input id="choice" type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="false">Kamar Taj
    </div>
    <div>
    <p>How did Dr Strange defeat Dormammu?</p>
    <input id="choice" type="radio" name="secondQuestion" value="false">Built An Energy Prison
    <input id="choice" type="radio" name="secondQuestion" value="true">Create a Time Loop
    <input id="choice" type="radio" name="secondQuestion" value="false">Froze Time
    </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitted()"/>
  </div>
  <p id="firstPara"></p>
  <p id="secondPara"></p>  
  </div>
</div>
```

On the other hand, @sjdm answered your question, when you use the correct selector for your input, you should be albe to apply the style to it/them.

```
#choice{
  width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

you can apply CSS like:

```
input[type="radio"] {
 width: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow one of the following two process:

```css
.row {
  margin: 50px;
}

/* --- Process One --- */
/* input[type=radio] {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
} */

/* --- Process Two --- */
input[type=radio] {
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="questions">
    What is the name of Black Panther's home?
    <br>
    <input id="choice" type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="false" >K'un Lun
    <input id="choice" type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="true">Wakanda
    <input id="choice" type="radio" name="firstQuestion" value="false" >Kamar Taj
    <br>
    How did Dr Strange defeat Dormammu?<br>
    <input id="choice" type="radio" name="secondQuestion" value="false" >Built An Energy Prison
    <input id="choice" type="radio" name="secondQuestion" value="true" >Create a Time Loop
    <input id="choice" type="radio" name="secondQuestion" value="false" >Froze Time
    <br>
    Which hero secretly has a family?<br>
    <input id="choice" type="radio" name="thirdQuestion" value="true" >Hawkeye
    <input id="choice" type="radio" name="thirdQuestion" value="false" >Wakanda
    <input id="choice" type="radio" name="thirdQuestion" value="false" >Kamar Taj
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitted()"/>
  </div>
  <p id="firstPara"></p>
  <p id="secondPara"></p>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to help me with solutions :)